# Jquery .Toggle() based on colgroup col id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, toggle, colgroup

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/8mqTs/).

I am having trouble grabbing the actual column by the colgroup's col id to toggle it.   I have the index correctly matched, but I do not understand how I can use the power of the colgroup to grab the entire column.  Here is my current attempt (all the way at the bottom on the fiddle):

```
    //Column Button Hider
    $('fieldset.techtable input.column[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
        var index = $(this).prevAll('input.column').length+2;
        console.log(index);
        $('fieldset.techtable' #col'+index').toggle()
            //($('#col'+index).toggle());
    });
```

and here is the table and colgroup:

```
<section class="techtable">
        <h1>Technologies / Compliance / Certifications</h1>
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <colgroup>
                <col id="col0">
                <col id="col1">
                <col id="col2">
                <col id="col3">
                <col id="col4">
                <col id="col5">
                <col id="col6">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Skill</th>
                    <th>Version(s)</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Elapsed Time</th>
                    <th>Expertise Rating</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Technology</td>
                    <td>J2EE</td>
                    <td>1.5, 1.6, 1.7</td>
                    <td>November, 2011</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>...repeating...</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
```

I want to try to utilize the power of the colgroup, but am unsure if I should use class ids (if so, where? on the col group id, the `<th>`? or each `<td>`?).

Are the `<th>`s interfering with the `<colgroup>`? maybe worded better, should I reference the th instead of trying to use colgroup?

A point in the right direction of syntax is helpful, and a line of code to help is always appreciated, but for this one, I am trying to avoid expanding this into more lines of code, unless im overlooking the methodology. I am under the assumption that I am not just grabbing  the col id correctly, but you feedback could prove me wrong.

Comment: Where is `fieldset.techtable`? All I see is `section.techtable`

Comment: Are you trying to hide an entire table column by hiding the col within colgroup? I wasn't able to make that actually do anything in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/HvGLu/ As far as your question about `th`, hiding a `th` will not hide it's corresponding `td`'s, they each have to be hidden separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to hide a particular column of data, hiding the col within the colgroup won't do it.

```
var colIndex = 0; // first column
$(myTable).find("td,th").filter(":nth-child(" + (colIndex+1) + ")").toggle();
```

I have modified this code to work with your table.  Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mqTs/1/)

```
 var index = $(this).prevAll('input.column').length+2;
 $('colgroup').parent('table').find("td,th").filter(":nth-child(" + (index+1) + ")").toggle();
```

Comment: Thank you for the information that colgroup won't hide it.  I think that is why I've been banging my head for over 2 hours.   Thank you greatly for helping a very Jr. Dev.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

```
$('fieldset.techtable #col' + index).toggle();
```

As the id is unique in the page, it normally is enough to just target that:

```
$('#col' + index).toggle();
```

Comment: yes, it is not working, although your line has an additional pair of single quotes than mine.

Comment: @chrisFrisina: Actually I removed a pair of apostophes.

Comment: oops, my mistake, referenced each other's wrong.

the second example correctly selects the correct colgroup, but nothing happens.   can the .toggle() be applied to the colgroup?

Comment: @chrisFrisina: Probably not. The colgroup isn't even a visual element. My experience is that it doesn't work very well to hide parts of a table anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

$(".techtable td:nth-child("+index+1+")").toggle();

saw this on: [Hide/Show Column in an HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455958/hide-show-column-in-an-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to toggle visibility of a column because columns are more metadata/pseudo-elements than actual elements on the page (it is actually the Nth `tr` of each `td` you're trying to toggle) . I know there are issues when attempting to style them consistently for this very reason (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257360/table-styling-col-class-should-override-over-td-class-how/8257761#8257761) for explanation/investigation).